# search on mysql filed for the number before first underscore

Tags: mysql

I have filed in my database called

> parcel_number

### containing from 2 parts first part the parcel number and the second one is sub parcel number between them is underscore like this:

12_1

12_2

2_2

21_2

if I want to search in the first part of a text, for example, I'm trying to select all part filed the part one exactly equal "2" I tried to like query with like {part%} or like {part_%} or {%part_} but without any luck

Comment: Seriously consider normalising your schema

Comment: @Akina this not work its return all result containing number 2

Comment: @Strawberry we can't change the database schema it's very large and so many functionalities using it

Comment: That sounds like an argument *for* changing it!

Answer (score 2):

Searching `parcel number = '2'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test 
WHERE '2' = SUBSTRING_INDEX(parcel, '_', 1);
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM test 
WHERE parcel LIKE CONCAT('2', '\_%');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ac0778c57ad2d3a90dfedfb7b96a65d)

If the index by `parcel` exists (separate, or this column is an index prefix) then the last query is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This *query* is your solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE CONCAT('2', '\_%');
```

It will concatenate '2' with whatever starts with '/_' using built-in *CONCAT* function